# @TransactionalEventListener, @Transactional and @Retryable flow

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-retry

When I publish CustomEvent in the end of `@Transactional` and `@Retryable(value = StaleStateException.class) method foo()`, how it is processed?

If I get `StaleStateException` during commit after method execution, then `@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)` won't called and by `@Retryable` Spring will call `foo()` second time. And what is lifecycle of first `CustomEvent` in this case? Will it be cleaned up? Or after second success call of `foo()`,`@TransactionalEventListener()` will be called twice?

Answer (score 1):

If someone will meet the same worry, answer is that events listened by TransactionalEventListener are alive only transaction-time. RetryTemplate creates new transaction for every call of @Retryable method, so only events from successful attempt will arrive to @TransactionalEventListener.